# Actual Size Album Art in iTunes 11

Tags: itunes, resolution, album-art

Prior to version 11, it was trivial in iTunes to view album artwork at "actual size". Is this possible in iTunes 11? It seems that all album artwork, regardless of the resolution of the file, is limited to the same measly 400x400 size dictated by the player.

Comment: As I know it can be done only by copy-pasting to get the image out. Is it enough for you or you just want to view it quickly?

Comment: I want to be able to view it as I could in previous versions, within the app while it was playing. I spent a decent amount of time and storage space (not tons, but a decent amount considering what it is) getting really nice, hi-res versions of a lot of my albums and now all of that seems wasted.

Comment: I HAD it by accident! I was listening to Men in Black and for some reason, I was able to right click with the listed options: "fit screen", "double size" or "actual size", etc - like back in the old days. Sad part is I don't know how I did it...